# Can't move toolbar from top/bottom to left/right and vice versa

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtoolbar

Just learning how to deal with QToolBar and figured out that can't change orientation by drag&dropping it.

```
    mainToolBar = QToolBar(self)
    mainToolBar.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.PreventContextMenu)
    mainToolBar.setFloatable(False)
```

As you can see, dropable field does not appear.
[image]

Comment: I figured out that problem caused by `centralWidget.setMinimumWidth(1000)`, but don't understand why that happens

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact that window at start tries to shrink to minimum possible size and it does not reserve space for `QToolBar`.
I have placed `QToolBar` to `Qt.TopToolBarArea` from start and reserved width:

```
    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.setMinimumSize(self.width() +
            self.mainToolBar.size().height(), self.height())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the QToolBar to not movable?

```py
mainToolbar.setMovable(False)
```